# Artist Seal Reading

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Can this artist's seal be deciphered?

[image]

Comment: It says Ｘ沱薺 or Ｘ池薺, I can't read Ｘ due to the ink smudging. If you know the last name of the artist, it may help.

Comment: “池”字可能更像，难道是“池齐明印”？

Answer (score 0):

You may rotate it CCW 90 degree, and the last two words seem to be "泣" and "齐"... But I'm not sure, because no one will use "泣"(it means weep) as his/her name

In seal character, they are

[image]

Comment: I have no idea if it is whats on this seal, but I have seen 泣 as a family name before.